# Since C++ knows type, can it infer dot and arrow?

Tags: c++, ide

Say I have this code

```
std::string s = "hello";
std::string* p = &s;
int l = p.length();
```

Visual Studio and CLion know dot operator is incorrect. Actually when I press key <kbd>.</kbd>, both IDE commit the keystroke as `->`.

Since C++ is typed, it knows p is a pointer, why doesn't it combine . and -> into one?

Can the syntax be to always use `.`, if p is pointer, dereference it first, otherwise directly get its member?

Comment: ***why doesn't it combine . and -> into one?*** Because those are different things. Also for smart pointers you use both.

Comment: Note that `->` can be overloaded, whereas `.` cannot.

Comment: Redundancy is helpful. Besides, there are smart pointers which need *both* `.` and `->` for different things.

Comment: What is the CLion's and VS hint for `s.begin().` and `s.begin()->`? ;)

Comment: What happens when you have `T`?  You don't know if it is a pointer or not.

Comment: @R2RT `s.begin()->` is an error.

Comment: Oups, you got me there. `char` does not have members... `std::vector<std::string>` would be better thing to explain my point. Anyway, the others have already found better explanation.

Comment: That would be Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes can overload the arrow operator, so there can be objects for which both `.` and `->` are valid. Smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`) and iterators are common examples.

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> f;
f.reset(new Foo(42));
f->bar();
```

Could you design a statically typed language without this distinction? Of course. But C++ has evolved this way, and that's not something you can change today without breaking tons of code.

Comment: If you read the duplicate, it becomes somewhat evident that C++ got the arrow operator purely by luck - we might never have it! Which would mean that overloading it would not be possible either (luckily it would not be introduced specifically for C++), and we wouldn't have smart pointers!

Comment: @SergeyA they are actually super interesting bits of history (from a time when C was way more similar to a glorified macro assembler) that I didn't know, thank you!